# update similar keywords in second table that are inside main table

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I do have two mysql tables where I would like to mark keywords inside the second table that are inside the main table.

e.g.:

main:

```
labrador
chihuahua
buldog
```

second

```
KEYWORD          SIMILAR
labrador puppies 1
red dogs         0
good medicine    1
```

Is this even possible with one mysql statement? I would try this with PHP, but hope to find a mysql only solution.

Something like:

```
UPDATE `keywords` 
SET SIMILAR = 1 
WHERE keyword  like (% SELECT KEYWORD FROM second %")
```

Has anybody an idea if this is doable and could give me a hint? Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect two tables with joins: [MySQL Inner Join Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

```
UPDATE
    keywords
INNER JOIN 
    second 
    ON keywords.KEYWORD LIKE '%', second.KEYWORDS ,'%'
SET
    keywords.SIMILAR = 1
WHERE
    keywords.SIMILAR = 0;
```

this query make only an update if the keyword in keywords table similar like keyword in your second table and doesn't yet marked as similar.

Comment: Hi rcro, thank you for your help. Your approach looks good, but somehow the syntax with the + sign must be wrong as mysql throws an error. This looks like a concat syntax?

Comment: oh i wrote to fast this answer: the + sign must be change to comma. i've updated  the answer. hope it works for you

Comment: Ok, I got the concat working now like this concat('%', cat.name , '%') . This executes without error, but does not have any effect. Are you sure that this approach with inner join could work?

Comment: Got it! The where statement was in the way. Empty rows have been NULL instead of 0. You might want to update your answer regarding concat.  Thank you for your help!